# Why GRASS 7.0.0 can't create a table while importing shapefiles from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I use GRASS7.0.0Beta1 and QGIS 2.4.0 on Windows8. With v.in.ogr, when I import a shapefile, I get the error message "Unable to create table". When I put the option of not importing the table, the vector file is imported. It used to work with GRASS6...

Comment: What database back-end are you using in GRASS? I believe this was defaulted to DBF or SQLite, but if you've tried to set it to something else without supplying the proper information (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc), it could be failing.

Comment: Please edit your posting and add the column names. Perhaps there are duplicate names?

Comment: I highly recommend to use the stable version of Grass (i.e 6.4.4.1).